# env windows parameter script

Tags: windows, parameters, env

I have a script that I want to execute from anther machine. I have a client that sends the command for starting the script.

The problem is that the script calls another script which is not run, because it can't find it.

If I run the first script from the machine it succeeded.
I tried to set the `PATH` env, but it seems that doesn't help.

Comment: If you use the shell to run a script over a network share, its effectively downloaded and run locally, is that the problem?

Comment: please post you scripts

Answer (score 0):

for windows user, if you delete **Env** by wrongly! 
follow these steps :
window `key + R` 
type : `Regedit` 
add this path in top of page  : `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment` 
next step edit `PATH` by right click in mouse and copy 
then open Environment Variable from the search bar in left down and type `Environment Variable` open and Edit path than past `CTRL + V` AND IT WILL BE FIXED